# Precision and F-score are ill-defined warning while using Python machine learning model

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

```
from sklearn import OneClassSVM

check = OneClassSVM(kernel='rbf', gamma='scale')
check.fit(X_train, y_train)
check.predict(X_test)
check.decision_function(X_train)
```

I am currently using OneClassSVM model. However, I made some changes to this in order to combine with other machine learning models. Originally, OneClassSVM model returns label values of -1 and 1, but I modified them to return 0 and 1. However, although there is no other error, it prints out the `Precision and F-score are ill-defined and being set to 0.0 in labels with no predicted samples. 'precision', 'predicted', average, warn_for` error.

**classification.py**

```
def classification_report(y_true, y_pred, labels=None, target_names=None,
                      sample_weight=None, digits=2, output_dict=False):
y_type, y_true, y_pred = _check_targets(y_true, y_pred)

labels_given = True
if labels is None:
    labels = unique_labels(y_true, y_pred)
    labels_given = False

else:
    labels = np.asarray(labels)

   labels = [0 if i==-1 else i for i in labels]
```

I don't understand why the error occurs because there is no special error. Personally, I think there might be a problem with labeling. However, I definitely need labels of 0 and 1, not -1 and 1 in the Oneclass model. I also checked that that error could be caused by insufficient data sets, so I doubled the data sets, but still get errors.

**result**

```
            precision    recall     f1-score   support
       A     0.0000      0.0000     0.0000     185698
       B     0.0059      0.7211     0.0117      735
accuracy     0.0059      0.0028     0.0038     186433
macro avg    0.0030      0.3605     0.0059     186433
weighted avg 0.0000      0.0028     0.0000     186433
```

The results I got are as above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you have a problem with your labels. There are some labels in `y_true`, which do not appear in `y_pred` and hence it is ill-defined.

You should double-check that both your `y_true` and `y_pred` use the same labels. From your snippet, it looks like you are modifying the `labels` array, not the `y_pred`.

Comment: My OneclassSVM's `y_true` contains [0,0,0,...,0] and `y_pred` contains [-1,-1,-1...,-1]. However, because I have to use OneClassSVM with other models together, I modified the `label` value, which contains the result of "unique_labeled values of `y_true` and `y_pred`". As written in the article, I changed the label value from -1 to 0 and then removed the duplicated elements. How can I fix y_pred?

Comment: You should change  `y_pred` so that it uses the same labels as `y_true` and use only the labels of `y_true` as they should be similar to the one used in `y_pred` after modification.

Comment: My `check.predict(X_test)` code returns [1,1,1....-1,-1] and this connects to y_pred. So it's right to deal with this value, right?

Comment: y_pred should use the 0 and 1 labels. Try to use `y_pred = np.where(y_pred==1, 1, 0)` and then use `sklearn.metrics.classification_report(y_true, y_pred)`.